# How to calculate $ \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(r+1\right)^{2}2^{-\left(2r-1\right)^{2}} $

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to calculate $ \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(r+1\right)^{2}2^{-\left(2r-1\right)^{2}} $ ?

I tried to differentiate term by term, but it did not lead me anywhere. Basically, I want to know if its possible to calculate this sum precisly, or the best we can do is find an upper bound for the mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally when you have a constant to a squared power as your summand you're going to be involving theta functions. The squared term out in front just means you're also involving the first and second derivatives of an appropriate theta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$a_r=\left(r+1\right)^{2}\,\, 2^{-\left(2r-1\right)^{2}}$$ the partial sums should convere very fast since
$$\frac{a_{r+1}}{a_r}=\left(\frac{r+2}{r+1}\right)^2\,2^{-8 r}$$ If we compute them
$$S_p=\sum_{r=0}^p  a_r$$ we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p\\
 0 & 0.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 2.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 2 & 2.5175781250000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
 3 & 2.5175786018371582031250000000000000000000000000000 \\
 4 & 2.5175786018372026120459850062616169452667236328125 \\
 5 & 2.5175786018372026120459998955126428997648713181690 \\
 6 & 2.5175786018372026120459998955126429181966227390624 \\
 7 & 2.5175786018372026120459998955126429181966227390625
\end{array}
\right)$$

To give you an idea, $a_{10}=2.576\times 10^{-107}$ and  $a_{100}=8.314\times 10^{-11918}$.

*Just for the fun*, if you accept an error of $6.0\times 10^{-10}$, an inverse symbolic calculator of mine proposes for the infinite sum
$$10 \sin \left(\frac{40 \pi }{381}\right) \cos \left(\frac{81 \pi }{374}\right)=\color{red}{2.51757860}78$$

Now, identifying the corresponding theta function is another story (I also would like to know the formal answer).

Comment: And the sum starting at $r=1$ is $2.0175786$

Comment: @GEdgar. Thanks for pointing it. Once more, my screen teller missed a bound.

Comment: To get the factor $(r+1)^2$ you will also need derivatives of theta functions.